# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. When using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having the Invalid Hook error in this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation, useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import $ from 'jquery'

import '../stylesheet/pages/pages.landing.css'
import '../stylesheet/global.css'

export default function Landing() {

    function useQuery() {
        return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        alert('a')
    }, [])
}
```

The error is in the useEffect line, can you guys help me?

The Landing is called on my Routes script:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Landing from './pages/Landing';

export default function routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact children={Landing} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where is `Landing` being called elsewhere, can you post the code?

Comment: In my routes.js file... Updating question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `children` prop gets called *as a normal function* [when you need to render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func), not as a component - hooks may only exist in elements created via JSX syntax, which transpiles to `React.createElement`.

While you could call the `Landing` with JSX syntax inside an inline `children` prop:

```
children={() => <Landing />}
```

It would be much more appropriate to use the [`component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) prop:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
```